# Problem with logo design: doesn't scale down well

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo

I need some advice/opinions on the attached logo and what my designer should have done to make it scaleable.

It looks fine at high resolution and zoomed in over 400% in AI, but at 100% and less the speech bubble is pixelated and loses definition.

[Here](http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) on the test site for example it looks like a dark pixelated mass with no colour detail as it has [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/Default.asp).

As we need it for the header, it's obviously a problem which he doesn't seem to see (or pretends not to) as he says it scales fine.

[image]

I've attached the favicon he did too which looks awful next to the twitter logo.

My questions are: is the speech bubble colour and definition shown in the larger version something that could likely be achieved at the size we need it for the header, approx. 200px?

[image]

If not, what should he do about it?

Any ideas or opinions appreciated.

Comment: Is `Scale Strokes & Effects` checked in the preferences or the Transform Panel before you scale? And realize that many logos require 2 or 3 versions to accommodate different uses. It's not unheard of to simplify the logo for small web use.

Comment: Just looked and it wasn't checked, but I checked it then scaled down and it looks the same. Thanks though, and yes he should definitely do a version to fit the web, but he says there's nothing wrong with it so I'm stuck for now unless he concedes.

Comment: May I also suggest to try and consider a different color palette?  At the present time you are using all dark colors and this quality will effect the logo when scaled.  Google search for [how to choose colors in a design](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+choose+colors+in+a+design&oq=how+to+choose+colors+in+a+design&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the colours are fine, it's the design that's wrong.

Comment: um..  the colors effect the design.  From 10' away looking at my screen I do not know or can easily tell what your script reads.  Not trying to be rude..  but THAT is an issue and THAT will cause your viewers to not understand or possibly go somewhere else if THAT type of quality is implemented in print or web.

Comment: More air would help a little. With that tight font, darkish colours and a relatively heavy shadow and outline, it will be hard to make anything small look good. The favicon is ludicrous though: your designer need to redesign that.

Comment: Font legibility is different, I agree on Mission Script being less than legible at small sizes and the heavy 3d affects that, we have a version with no 3d and less 3d which work well and this one's being amended to have slightly less 3d to make it more legible along with hopefully a new speech bubble that scales well.  It's just the design that's wrong, the colours are fine, it's the combination of heavy 3d and intricacy of the speech bubble that don't work and aren't scaleable.  Appreciated your comments, I just mean't to clarify why the design wouldn't work

Comment: Are you saying color plays no effect in design then?

Comment: Well yes and no, but it's a moot issue.

Comment: Are you paying the designer? Where does Photoshop come in to this?

Comment: Yep, he's being paid. Do you see what I'm saying? Sorry yes I'd pasted the logo from illustrator to photoshop as a smart object and wondered if he'd done anything in PS too as it's not coming out right in illustrator, so tagged it there just in case.

Comment: It is valid for Photoshop though - sometimes logos are rasterized there from AI and effects/blurs applied which aren't the same in AI.

Comment: Are you able to come into the [chat]? I have more questions, and the comments aren't a great venue for discussion

Comment: @boblet, I agree totally, we have a version with more spacing for smaller sizes and this one works with a smaller 3d effect, but the speech bubble just doesn't scale and the 3d is too heavy. Yeah the favicon's a joke.

Comment: @JohnB Just tried to go in there, but it's saying I need a 20 reputation or more. Thanks though for the comments

Comment: You should have access now

Comment: Sorry John, I was emailing him trying to get it fixed yesterday. I'm free today though? I've done a redesign as a last resort in greys and no 3d (via the link posted above)

Comment: I like the script style as it's unique for our industry and denotes the advertiser communicating their message with the customers, but with a personal touch. We only provide quality content and think the colours/3d detract from that. It also looks more legible now, but introducing another new design so soon is worrying

Answer (score 3):

Im adding this as an answer because my comments are going to be too long:

Per the comment segment:

> May I also suggest to try and consider a different color palette? At
>   the present time you are using all dark colors and this quality will
>   effect the logo when scaled. Google search for how to choose colors in
>   a design.

From Sue

> Thanks for the suggestion, the colours are fine, it's the design
>   that's wrong.

My response:

> um.. the colors effect the design. From 10' away looking at my screen
>   I do not know or can easily tell what your script reads. Not trying to
>   be rude.. but THAT is an issue and THAT will cause your viewers to not
>   understand or possibly go somewhere else if THAT type of quality is
>   implemented in print or web.

If you look at your logo reduced like this:

[image]

Can you actually read that?  You can, because you know the company but if you ask 10 people that never heard of you or know who you are they will tell you NO.  You should strongly consider:

- Color Change
- Better usage of stroke
- Better usage of typography

That script is small enough as it is to be introducing a harsh stroke.

---

In regards to your `.png` files:

[image]

There is no unity or marriage between them.  The twitter is a nice solid color with spacing and your lasso is multi-colored that appears to be a bad reduction. What should possibly be done is:

- Better usage of space:
- Possible implementation of one color usage like the twitter logo.

Also, per your question alone I don't understand why, if you see issues at fault, you are not correcting them yourself instead of going through a designer?  How is your communication with the designer? Have you addressed or communicated with the designer?

Reference: [How can I provide better direction for how I want my logo to look?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22547/how-can-i-provide-better-direction-for-how-i-want-my-logo-to-look/22548#22548)

Comment: Thanks Matt, appreciate the answers. The logo size you gave as an example though would be hard to read for most logo designs, but we have a version with more spacing and no 3d for very small sizes. The 3d effect is being slightly adjusted anyway and the colours work, it's just the style used with the heavy 3d and intricate speech bubble as mentioned. Appreciate all comments/opinions and they've all helped.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't focus on one solid logo, that defines your company, to be designed and used across the board, for multiple sizes and devices.

Comment: I agree with the theory and it's what I'd usually commission, but it's mainly web based communications we operate and devices will handle the logo. We also have one with no 3d for smaller uses which works fine and transitions well.

Comment: The favicon was more a representation of the type of work he submitted as "looking fine" and "scaleable", both of which are not. Simply to highlight the mess he'd made of the favicon.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i think  what your designer did here is ignoring the fact of legibility and readability and these 2 are main elements to design a logo that's why we create a logo guideline book so we can help the user to use the logo in multiple applications ( CMYK, RGB, BW , GREYSCALE, Printed, Digital etc...) and also in the guideline we include a color palette and the Min-Size of our logo.

On the other hand, the problem here seems to be a bit technical, while using illustrator. Your designer should always be sure that scale stroke & Effects is checked so the software by itself sets the values of all the effects, and when exporting the logo to png or jpg, he has to follow the right way : If exporting for web, he should be using save for web and devices option and to be sure to choose the right values of quality and colors. if exporting for printing we prefer that the file must be Using CMYK Format and Tif HR.

also there is one important element to be aware of. when you are using ur logo for the website make sure it is in RGB Format and not in CMYK Format, this can cause a bit of a problem when it comes to gradients and shadows.

at the end i also suggest that the lines around the logo has to be drawn not to be applied using the Bevel effect because this effect is knows to cause many problems.

As for the FAVICON let your designer create is in its real size, 16 x 16 or 32 x 32 and i advise u to use one color favicon cz its more legible.

If you want other advises on how to know if scale stroke and effects is checked of you would like me to suggest a favicon for you do not hesitate to ask