# What is the right way to ensure design you really want?

Tags: logo, business, client-relations

When working with logo designer, what is the correct model of communication in helping designer to envision what you want and improving chances of delivering what I have in mind?

Do I "direct" the designer to what I feel should be on logo or just fill out questionnaire with information what my business does, demographic metrics, company slogan? I had experience of "directing" designer and it wasn't as I wanted it to be, maybe because the designer just followed my direction and didn't have something in mind?

Comment: Related: [How can I write requirements for a graphic designer?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18569/how-can-i-write-requirements-for-a-graphic-designer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would not necessarily impose a design to a designer unless you can back it up with sound marketing and communication strategy. The designer may surprise you with a fresh look on your business that you had not imagined. I would also make sure to get a few options to compare what might be a better fit (3 is usually a good number).

If you do need to have a specific example, don't be afraid to provide images of things that look like what you want or have parts that correspond to what you want. Be specific about what parts and why. Too often, clients will have something in their mind but how they communicate their needs is abstract to the designer. Things like: "Can you jazz this up?" and such.

Obviously, like Vincent said, hire a professional designer and expect to build a long-term professional relationship with them. They will help you flesh out your vision and build a strong corporate image for your business.

Comment: I see that communication is essential and it would be more logical to pay more and hire designer who listens and where we could speak "same language" than to hire designer from non-English speaking country?

Comment: Indeed, same language is preferable but also, remember that if you hire a designer from another country, his visual culture will also be different which may not work for your audience in the end.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost: hire a real designer, and don't succumb to the lure of all the design contest spec work sites or competitions. A good, professional designer will guide you in this process, instead of you having to guide them. Yes, be prepared to pay more. You get what you pay for.

Comment: Are you referring to 99designs website where designers win client's bid?

Comment: Among others, yes. Spec work like this is horrible for both the quality of the design you're getting and the design industry as a whole.

Comment: All who use them say they are awesome because you end up with so many good looking designs that it's hard to pick one.

Comment: If you want to discuss the cons of spec work, I propose that we [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot). You're never going to convince me, though :)

Comment: Learn more about spec work:  http://www.nospec.com/