# Responsibilities and requirements for graphic designer position

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign

I plan to recruit a graphic designer for my organization, but I'm not sure how to put/assign the responsibility to him/her. I have read this post: [How can I write requirements for a graphic designer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18569/18640), but I'm still having a hard time defining this clearly.

What specific, general responsibilities would be expected for a graphic designer position?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what the designer will be doing in order to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Counter question: Why do you think you need a graphic designer? In order to write proper requirements you need to define first what is missing in your business communication.

Comment: Thank both for your idea, we want to create new logo , advertising material such as flyer, leaflet, banner, name card etc. and other more as requires

Comment: do you need a designer with proper education (b. des) and are you willing to pay for such?

Comment: Sure, we need someone skillful can work for us (no need to train again) don't care much about payment, because we need to pay for some do us the job well.

Comment: you didn't answer my question :) - is education important to you? Someone with a design degree?

Comment: Hi @Naty: it's does not mater with me for the design degree or not, but just need someone can do my job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the requirements should be:
1. Knowledge in Photoshop Illustrator, Indesign **must** 
2. Flash, Premiere, After effects, HTML, CSS, etc. would be a bennefit
3. Experience in branding, print design and web design
4. Knowledge of print processes
5.Send a portfolio with a CV obviously!

You need to explain that they will be in charge of the entire brand of your company (instead of studios where you work for one projects after another) and every designed aspect of the company is under their responsibility.
Obviously explain about the company what they do and what does your brand mean.

Comment: Thank @Naty for your help :) I will follow your advise and get one very soon

Comment: Unless you need someone to produce videos and animations for you, you don't need skills in Flash, Premiere, AfterEffects. If they aren't developing web content, they don't need HTML, CSS.  If you are having marketing collateral printed, you need someone knowledgeable with the print process including paper specification.

Comment: I disagree with #1 and 2. Knowing software shouldn't be the primary skill you are looking for. #5 is key and should be #1. Technical expertise is important, of course, but a competent designer should be able to pick up nearly any design software that is needed on the job. Knowing the concepts is much more important than the particular keyboard shortcuts.